# String validation with a pattern with php

Tags: php

I need to check a string like `1234567 01-01-74` (without the quotes).

My string's first numeric value has to be 7 digits in length, followed by space, then a date string with `-` between the day, month and year digits.

How do I do that?

Comment: Should avoid this question because of regular expression fanboys.. but  I'll try to help anyhow..  Does the date have to be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following regular expression should work:

```
(\d{7}) \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

Using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) we can test to see if a string is valid or not:

```
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if(preg_match("/(\d{7}) \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/i", "1234567 01-01-74")) 
{
    // Valid string code here
    echo "Valid";
}
else 
{
    // Bad string code here
    echo "Not valid! Ogblog!";
}
```

Comment: Not a problem Raj. Don't forget to mark this as correct and upvote if it all works out :-)